# Uniting urls for a download utility (like wget) in one line

Tags: command-line, wget, curl, download

Consider these `wget` codes:

```
wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/papj.sh
wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/nixta.sh
```

Is there any elegant way to unite different terminals of the same basic URL as above, into one line instead 2 or more?

Pseudocode:

```
wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/papj.sh||nixta.sh
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `wget` accepts several URLs at once this can be done using brace expansion in `bash`:

```
wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/{papj.sh,nixta.sh}
```

(or even

```
wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/{papj,nixta}.sh
```

but this only works for well-suited names of course).

Comment: Thanks, allow me to ask, off label - would you consider this a best practice or something commonly done by professional Bash programmers? (at least, the first option which should be with less confusing).

Comment: @Arcticooling Hmm, good question. For URLs it may not make a lot of sense because it prevents easy copy/paste in case you need to access the same file in the browser, I probably wouldn't use it at least. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace says "it's used to generate mass-arguments for a command, that follow a specific naming-scheme.", http://linuxg.net/curly-brackets-expansion-in-bash-with-5-practical-examples/ has some good examples, I use the `cp /path/to/file{,.bak}` thing regularly (but mostly interactively, not in scripts).

Comment: "this only works for well-suited names" – What names do you think it would not work for?

Comment: @HaukeLaging the second option, which uses brace expansion only for part of the file name, requires file names ending in a common part.

Comment: @patrix It makes a lot of sense for URLs; very useful. Oftentimes, a gallery of images on a webpage will have the different image urls differ only by a consecutive number, and so you can do `wget http://example.com/img-{1..70}.jpg` or similar to download them all.

Comment: @JoL Right, pattern was probably the term I was looking for. Thanks for adding this.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using awk command and for loop. Let me know for any doubts and confusion

Created one file example.txt by putting below content in a file

cat example.txt

```
wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/
```

I have assigned  papj.sh nixta.sh to the variable i

Used below script to execute as per your requirement

```
for i in papj.sh nixta.sh; do awk -v i="$i" '{print $0i}' example.txt; done
```

Output

```
wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/papj.sh

wget -P ~/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/nixta.sh
```